# Heapster + InfluxDB on Google Container Engine (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to figure out what the best way to run Grafana/Heapster/InfluxDB on my GKE Kubernetes cluster.

From what I understand I cannot modify the `kube-system` namespace unless I want google to overwrite these settings after a time. So changing the heapster that is running in kube-system is probably not an option.

Does that mean I need another heapster in my default namespace alongside grafana and InfluxDB pods?

Comment: You might want to have a look at these discussions [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kubernetes-users/influxDB|sort:relevance/kubernetes-users/kZrVrUSBt5M/jmzxFC33BAAJ) and [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kubernetes-users/influxDB|sort:relevance/kubernetes-users/Tt0jH6-p7I8/bXeqrr_cDgAJ).

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Comment: @Tigraine, Did you solve that?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I gave up and we are now using prometheus